# How to revoke users application access using OpenId Connect with implicit flow?

Tags: openid, identityserver4

I'm assuming this is a standard scenario nevertheless I didn't find any good answers. If user is disabled by application administrator how can his access to application be revoked immediately ? He would still have valid tokens at least until they expire.

Would the solution be to check in API on each request if the user is active and maybe cache the result? Or is there something else the standard proposes in such a scenario ?

We are using: Angular6 + ASP.NET Core 2 + Identity Server 4.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `reference tokens` and `introspection` which basically achieves what you were describing - api calls the authority provider and exchanges the reference tokens for access tokens, so the revocation by administrator on the central authority is immediately effective.

Before you embark on this approach, make sure you understand the pros and cons as generally immediate revocation of rights is not needed and that is somewhat achieved by short lived access tokens.

Comment: Well let's say user is found to be a security risk. Isn't it a valid scenario to revoke his access immediately ?

Comment: @MateuszMigała Of course it might be a valid scenario. I am not claiming that it isn't and if you were building software for missile control centre - then the severity of non immediate access revocation can be huge. However, that is what you need to identify - whether it is worth implementing reference token usage and introspection. Remember, you can reduce the lifetime of short lived access to 15 min or whatever you deem is acceptable timeframe.